# Programmatically list included Java libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I am working on a project that utilizes many security/utility libraries. For security reasons, I would like to be able to inform the user which libraries we use and what version is running in their bin. Many of our users chose to modify our code so I would prefer it to do so programmatically.

I attempted to parse the classpath but that doesn't seem to help when the program is packaged into a jar. I have also tried listing all of the class names in the JAR, but this doesn't convey any version information.

All of our libs have the version in the name of the jar file. I'm open to making some kind of compile-time script. We build using ant and intellij. Ant is the only one I need to support, intellij just makes life easier.

Comment: Current classpath is available at runtime via system property 'java.class.path' that should give you the jar filenames. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Give an example of jars you are trying to get. They're all under class path folder? and are the jars such as external-jar-name.jar the jar under the class path and that is what you are trying to get?

Comment: That worked great when I was using intellij, but when I compiled it to a jar it stopped working. This makes sense because the libs are unpacked and included in the jar as .class files. I think if I want to remember lib file names, I will need some kind of ant script to record them into a txt file.

Comment: Don’t try to automate this.  You know what libraries you’re using, so make the list yourself as an explicit text file.  This also serves as documentation of your dependencies, which is a very good thing for developers to have.

Comment: VGR, Yes, I can do it that way, but for the reasons java neophyte pointed out, it is far from ideal. This is a project with many contributors, dozens of libs, and nearly daily changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by parsing the META-INF/maven/org/blah/pom.properties files. It only works for libs that have maven support (though your project doesn't need anything maven related).

```
private static HashMap<String,String> getVersionMap () {
    //Results by <lib name, version>
    final HashMap<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        //Hack to get a ref to our jar
        URI jarLocation = new URI("jar:" + SecurityInfo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString());
        //This jdk1.7x nio util lets us look into the jar, without it we would need ZipStream
        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarLocation, new HashMap<String,String>());

        Files.walkFileTree(fs.getPath("/META-INF/maven"), new HashSet<FileVisitOption>(), 3, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
                if (file.toString().endsWith(".properties")) {
                    try {
                        List<String> data = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
                        String id = data.get(4);
                        id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
                        String version = data.get(2);
                        version = version.substring(version.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
                        resultMap.put(id, version);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ignore) {}
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception ignore) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the jar is in the class path you can use system properties to get the jars.

```
  String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
  String[] p;
  p = path.split(";");
  for(int i=0; i< p.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(p[i]);
  }
```

For the example above is what I used to return all my web app libraries from the server. You can do similar to get the jars you want.

If you packaged them into a jar then you need to load it from the class directory itself you can try classloader.

```
 ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
 URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)loader).getURLs();
 for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
 }
```

Comment: This worked while the project is in intellij. When I build using ant though, the resulting jar has all of the important libs built in, and therefore lists only the jar itself as the classpath.

Comment: try use classLoader to load the jars instead.

Comment: Same issue. The jars are actually unpacked into folders and .class files rather than being included as jars. As a result any version information is lost. I feel as though the solution involves saving the jar names via an ant script.